# sqlalchemy, setting MySQL charset as `create_engine` argument

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I create `sqlalchemy` engine connecting to MySQL database. I want to specify `charset` as [`create_engine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#dialect-mysql-mysqldb-connect) argument.

If I use `create_engine` liKe that:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://pd:pd@localhost/pd?charset=utf8')
```

then all is fine. But, when I use it like that:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://pd:pd@localhost/pd', charset='utf8')
```

then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Invalid argument(s) 'charset' sent to create_engine(), using
    configuration MySQLDialect_mysqldb/QueuePool/Engine. Please check that
    the keyword arguments are appropriate for this combination of components.
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#engine-creation-api), this usage should be possible:

> The string form of the URL is
>   dialect+driver://user:password@host/dbname[?key=value..] ...
>
> **kwargs takes a wide variety of options which are routed towards their appropriate components. Arguments may be specific to the Engine,
>   the underlying Dialect, as well as the Pool. Specific dialects also
>   accept keyword arguments that are unique to that dialect. Here, we
>   describe the parameters that are common to most create_engine() usage.

Why I cannot specify `charset` separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the additional DBAPI arguments, when passed separately, are passed via [connect_args](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html#custom-dbapi-args).

Comment: Link is empty "Page Not Found!"

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sqlalchemy.engine.url`.[URL](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL) class

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

DB = {
    'drivername': 'mysql',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '3306',
    'username': os.environ['DBUNAME'],
    'password': os.environ['DBPASS'],
    'database': os.environ['DBNAME']
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**DB), connect_args={'charset':'utf8'})
```

Or even better

```
DB = {
    'drivername': 'mysql',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'port': '3306',
    'username': os.environ['DBUNAME'],
    'password': os.environ['DBPASS'],
    'database': os.environ['DBNAME'],
    'query': {'charset':'utf8'}
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**DB))
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL) `URL` class has the following parameters

> - drivername – the name of the database backend. This name will correspond to a module in sqlalchemy/databases or a third party
>     plug-in.
> - username – The user name.
> - password – database password.
> - host – The name of the host.
> - port – The port number.
> - database – The database name.
> - query – A dictionary of options to be passed to the dialect and/or the DBAPI upon connect.

Comment: Can I specify any connection proxy here?